# iOS getting a random NSTimeInterval error "initializing 'NSTimeInterval (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to get a random point in time between 0 and  time interval but I'm getting this error:

> "initializing 'NSTimeInterval (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

This is my code:

```
NSTimeInterval time=[timer lenghtOfTime];
NSTimeInterval newTime = [random NextDouble:0.0 :time];  // <---here is were I'm getting the error.
```

Comment: Show the declaration for your `NextDouble::` method.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like your NextDouble:: method returns some kind of NSObject; NSTimeInterval is just a typedef for a plain double primitive.